# How is a mixed order tensor compatible with the usual definition of a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors

Typically one will find the definition of the set of $(p,q)$-rank tensor fields on the manifold $M$ as something like
$$
\mathcal{T}^p_q(M):=\Gamma(\underbrace{TM \otimes \cdots\otimes TM}_p \otimes \underbrace{T^*M \otimes \cdots \otimes T^*M}_q)
$$
What if I have a tensor of mixed rank, and mixed order? For instance, something as simple as $\mathrm{d}x\otimes \partial_x\otimes\mathrm{d}y\in\Gamma(T^*M\otimes TM \otimes T^*M)$. This may look like a $(1,2)$-rank tensor but I cannot meaningfully add it to, say $\partial_y \otimes \mathrm{d}x \otimes \mathrm{d}y\in\Gamma(TM\otimes T^*M \otimes T^*M)$, since $\Gamma(T^*M\otimes TM \otimes T^*M)\neq\Gamma(TM\otimes T^*M \otimes T^*M)$.

1. How does one take a mixed order tensor to the form we have defined above?
2. Does one avoid this by using the metric to relate $g:TM \to T^*M$ and vice versa?

Comment: You just permute the tensor factors appropriately.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan permute them how? The tensor product isn't generally symmetric.

Comment: Perhaps Qiaochu means that it must be use isomorphisms like $T^*M\otimes TM\cong TM\otimes T^*M$

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The tensor product satisfies $V \otimes W \cong W \otimes V$ so it is symmetric in that sense. They aren't literally equal but they can be canonically identified.